# How to refer to another Java project from current project?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, buildpath

I used `Eclipse` to build a java application `(Project A)` which uses another `(Project B)` as reference. I just need to add `Project B` in Java Build path/Projects so i can run locally the main function from `Project A`.

## Problem

When I deploy A to GAE, if A's `doGet` has B's classes, then GAE complains that it can't find it.  Sure the war folder in A doesn't have anything that are in B.

## Question

How do I let GAE deployment tool to upload all needed classes from B in order to run A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add project B as a library to Project A.

> How to I let GAE deployment tool to upload all needed classes from B in order to run A?

If you add Project B as library to Project A, they automatically become one project,meaning where ever project A goes, B follows.

Try reading these:

[Eclipse - Importing your own library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632193/eclipse-importing-your-own-library)

[Android Library projects](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html) (this one shows you how to mark a project as library etc)

Comment: The Elipse - Importing your own library has a reply not marked as answer which mentioned to add sources.  That solved my problem.