# How to import one Eclipse project as a library into another?

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I would like to use one of my eclipse projects in another one. Is there a 'smooth' way to do that, without having to export one as a jar file and importing it into another? Especially since I work on both project simultaneously, I would like the latest changes from the imported project to be automatically built and imported into the other one. Is that possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible. Right click on your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path. Switch to the Projects tab and add one. It will work as a library.

P.S. You might also want to check this: [Creating a java library with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213871/creating-a-java-library-with-eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

Answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3632269/1844843) explains how to import your own library in eclipse.

Quoting from the answer.

> Just have "Project" reference your "Library", on windows the process
>   is (using menu / tab names)
>
> 1. Go to: Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects
> 2. Client Add...
> 3. Select your "Library" project from the list
> 4. Click Ok
> 5. Click the other Ok Now your done and you can use import for classes in your "Library"